# Reusing of built application's libraries and functions

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have an application that already built, is there any way to reuse the functionalities of that application without having its source code.

Something like including .dll files that come with that application... is that possible?

The idea is that I want to extend the fuctionalities of some application's search engine, it is so basic, so I thought that I can use that engine to get those basic results and then narrow them to match search query better or to perform more than one search for single user search to get near results (like google does)...

Comment: Yes, you can add a reference. What have you tried?

Comment: I didn't try this solution, I thought it is bit more complicated, anyway I want to know now how to know what methods are in a .dll file and how to know which ones are used for searching by that application. Besides I want to know if there is a way to replace a .dll file by another one with same name or edit the existing by adding methods or removing ones... That's the next to search for. Thank you for answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is.

Just *right click* on References in your project,
go to the *Assemblies* tab,
click *Browse*
and select the dll you want to add.

Comment: does that give me the ability to do things that I added in the previous edit... please read it, and thank you for fast response :)

Comment: @A.Harkous yes, it does. Why wouldnt it give you that option? If you can use the search engine defined in that assembly, you can certainly get the results and narrow them down.

Comment: Ok, I thought that .dll files just link your application to where the source code of the targeted functions is!